# Will marriages continue when mashiach comes?

Tags: history, marriage, messiah

If you are married to a girl and mashaich comes, wil you be married to her in the world to come or you start all over?!?

Comment: This reminds me of the question "when moshiach comes and the dead come back, if a women was a widow of a tzadik and then remarried, which husband will she be with?"

Comment: @avi, why of a _tzadik_ specifically? Wouldn't the same question arise about any second husband — or wife?

Comment: Because some might argue that a non-tzadik doesn't get resurrected. And so undo the question.

Answer (score 13):

According to the Rambam (Laws of Kings 12:1), the natural world we know will continue to exist in Moshiach's times. So yes, marriages existing now will still be in effect when Moshiach comes.

Even according to the opinions that it will be an era of miracles and of a new natural order (Ramban), we'll still be physical creatures with bodies.

Comment: @Vram, why should it? As per Shmuel Brill's answer below, it's indeed uncertain which husband she'll be married to at that time - but she will indeed be married to one and only one of them, either way. (That said, I understood the original question to be about people who are alive when Moshiach comes. What happens to marriages dissolved by death before that - that's a different issue.)

Answer (score 2):

Rambam also makes a distinction between "the world to come" and "the times of Moshiach". "The world to come" (shamayim/olam-haba) refers to a spiritual world separate from our physical world. Our neshama goes to "the world to come" after we die and waits there until the times of messiah and resurrection (& I think if you die after the resurrection, you go back there).

When you get married, your neshama is bound to your wife's and you are like one person. So there is a permanent connection made in the spiritual realm as well as in the physical world, so the bonds of marriage also still hold in messianic-times/post-resurrection/the-world-to-come.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/to-live-and-live-again/13.htm#t373

A divorcee who remarries will remain married to her second husband upon Resurrection. There is a difference of opinion as to the status of a widow who remarries.